# sending events synchronized with video stream

Tags: wpf, events, video, stream, rtsp

I would like to get video stream with some real-time events synchronized with it. For example I would like to have a possibility to unlock a button, after something on the screen happenened - when something happens in front of the camera, there should be send some info about it (i.e. cameraman is pushing special button). The quest is to have this info (or event) synchronized with situation on the screen. Is it possible to send and receive such metadata using RTSP? The application will be written in WPF.

I need to get functionality very similar to this one:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/metadata_video_streaming.html
offered by flash, but on .NET platform. Do you know any libraries that could help me?

http://www.streamingmedia.com/conferences/west2010/presentations/SMWest-2010-Microsoft-Workshop.pdf

Comment: What do you mean with something on the screen happened? Do you want to have some kind of image detection?

Comment: no, as now mentioned in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 2 solutions that are offering requied functionality. First one is Microsoft Media Server. It's offered by MIcrosoft, so it's quite easy to use it in WPF. The problem here is that it's not a Real Time protocol. For me lags about 10-20 seconds (on localhost) were not acceptable.

The second one is Flash Media Streaming Server using RTMP. It also offers requied functionality and what is more as it's name says it's Real Time protocol. Lags here were unnoticeable (usually much lower than 1 second on localhost). But as it's Flash technology it must be handled by Flash code. I resolved it by putting Flash componnent inside ActiveX formant. For me it was my perfect match ;)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, RTSP is not offering such a possibilty to send additional MetaData.

Maybe you could put some meta data into the extension header of the RTP (video-) frames.

Another way is to start a parallel meta data stream (XML i.e.). On the client side you synchronize both streams like it is done for audio/video streaming.

good luck.

Comment: I was thinking about sending it separately, but I have no I idea how to synchronize video stream (sent through some special protocol) with norrmal serialized data (propably sent through WCF or http). Don't you have any clues?

Comment: which timestamps? these used by protocol?

Comment: temporal synchronization is done best with synchronized timestamps you put inside both streams/metadata. RTP/RTCP offers possibilities to transmit the absolute and relative time codes together with the (video-)stream.